# Word-wrap doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I have a select.

[image]

It displays well in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

[image]

My code is here: jsfiddle.net/oxtdxq5h/1/

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems to be white-space:pre-wrap or -moz-pre-wrap. I haven't tested it as I just seen your code from my mobile.

After investigating I came to know browser does not support such breaks. Chrome has took an exception over it.

Comment: in my code : ` word-wrap: break-word;
  /* IE*/
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
  /* Firefox */
  white-space: pre-wrap;`